# Ожидание завершения AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Написал класс обработки post запроса через AsyncTask и принимаю ответ от сервера. Как приостановить главный поток, чтобы дождаться выполнения AsyncTask'a? При вызове метода Thread.currentThread.wait(int) - получаю исключение "InvocationTargetException"

---

Нужно сделать так, чтобы активность могла обработать полученный результат от AsyncTask, а не выполнялась вперед его завершения.

Comment: гуглил много - толка мало

Comment: А зачем тогда делать asynctask если ты хочешь в главном потоке? Делай прям в главном запрос, в чем проблема? На то он и asynctask чтобы не ждать пока он выполнится.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нельзя отправлять POST-запрос на сервер, из главного потока.

Comment: Тогда ответ ниже, это есть правильный ответ для вашей задачи

Comment: Суть проблемы он не решает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока `AsyncTask` работает, показывайте поверх своего приложения диалог с `ProgressBar`, и надписью `Loading...`, например. А в методе `onPostExecute()` обрабатывайте результат выполнения `AsyncTask`.

---

Никогда не заставляйте главный поток висеть. Это будет выглядеть так, какбудто ваша программа зависла, и Android предложит ее убить.

Comment: Мысль достойная, но не искоренит мою проблему.
Мне нужно обработать результат AsyncTask'a. Я хочу это сделать в главном потоке. Если я запущу диалоговую активность на время работы AsyncTask'a - код главной активности не приостановится.
Иначе я могу просто написать последующий код в onPostExecute, но мне нужно работать в вглавном классе.

Comment: @Jorik, у вас не получится так сделать. Пересмотрите свой код таким образом, чтобы обрабатывать результат в `onPostExecute`. Вы не под каким поводом не должны *вешать* главный поток никогда.

Comment: @Jorik, я не могу придумать ни одной причины, почему вам необходимо работать исенно в главном классе

Comment: потому что не хочу переделывать кучу параметров так, чтобы к ним можно было обращаться из других классов. Нужно выполнить поставленную задачу в обработчике onClick и перейти дальше.

Comment: @Jorik, к сожалению, я могу помочь только с правильным решением. Со струганием костылей - увы, помогать не тану. Вам придется либо сделать правильно с нашей помощью, либо самому делать костыли.

Comment: Смысл в том, что мне после получения верного ответа с сервера нужно будет запустить другую активность. Разве это возможно сделать из вспомогательного потока?

Comment: @Jorik, а `onPostExecute` выполняется в главном потоке

Comment: Да, но так как он описывается в другом классе, заменить его будет намного сложнее, так как придется переписывать половину кода, который удобнее выполнить в MainActivity

Comment: наверное мне стоит перефразировать задачу

Comment: @Jorik, вы ошибаетесь, я думаю. Мне кажется, переделывать нужно минимум. Стартовать `Activity` в `onPostExecute` очень просто: `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, НоваяАктивити.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Главный поток нельзя останавливать, если поток остановится то ос сочтет что приложение зависло и убьет его.